# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE not loading files to database

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, csv

I have a .csv file I want to import to the database using LOAD DATA INFILE. The csv file contains over 3000 rows and 5 columns. After running the code below, I got an error message:

> (22, "File 'MyScripts\name.csv' not found (Errcode: 22)")

conn_mysql is in the same directory with name.csv. Please any help will be much appreciated.

```python
import MySQLdb
login_info = open("MyScripts\\conn_mysql.txt").read()
login_info = login_info.split()

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=login_info[0],port=int(login_info[1]),user=login_info[2],passwd=login_info[3],db="test")
print("Connected")
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'MyScripts\\name.csv' \
  INTO TABLE names \
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' \
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  \
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' \
  IGNORE 1 LINES;;"""
try:
   cursor.execute(sql)
   conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
      print("%s" % e)
      conn.rollback()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Follow-up questions from someone who doesn't know a word about Python... Are you really sure your code would actually display errors if something went wrong? You only have a try/catch block that leaves no other trace than a silent rollback...

Comment: File not found... Is the file really there? Does it work if you don't rely on relative paths and type a full absolute path?

Comment: Windows ought to understand forward-slashes in path names. Replace `\\ ` with `/` and see what happens.